# Angular 6 : Cannot read property of undefined after second initialization of dynamically created component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-components, angular-dynamic-components

I am trying to create a component dynamically which has a model class to initialize.

**Here is my issue I am facing :**
[image: Console Error]

**It works when I create component once and then when I try second time it says the problem**

**Here are my codes :**

**.HTML**

```
<div [formGroup]="articleCategoryGeneralBodyEditForm">
 <input type="hidden" formControlName="category_details_language_id" [(ngModel)]="article_category_detail.category_details_language_id">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category_details_name"><strong class="form-control-required">*</strong> Category Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_details_name" placeholder="Enter category name | ex: Parent" formControlName="category_details_name" [(ngModel)]="article_category_detail.category_details_name">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**.COMPONENT.TS**

```
export class ElSubGeneralBodyEditComponent implements OnInit {

// Models
article_category_detail: ArticleCategoryDetail = new ArticleCategoryDetail();

// Form
articleCategoryGeneralBodyEditForm: FormGroup;

constructor(public _DataSharerService: DataSharerService, private _ToasterService: ToasterService, private _BlogArticleCategoryService: BlogArticleCategoryService) { }

setForm() {
  this.articleCategoryGeneralBodyEditForm = new FormGroup({
    category_details_name: new FormControl(),
    category_details_language_id: new FormControl()
  });
  this.article_category_detail.category_details_language_id = this._DataSharerService.getLanguageId()[0];
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.setForm();
}
}
```

**this is how I am creating the component dynamically :**

```
createEditFormComponent() {

this.editFormContainerRef.clear();
const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ElCategoriesEditComponent);
this.componentRef = this.editFormContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
this.componentRef.instance.thisComponentRef = this.componentRef;
}
```

**And this is how I am destroying the created component :**

```
onClose() {
  this.thisComponentRef.destroy();
}

/* Please be noted, ElCategoriesEditComponent is a parent component of ElSubGeneralBodyEditComponent */
```

**I have done the same for other components, they are working fine except the different between other components and this component (ElCategoriesEditComponent ) is that this component has a child component.**

I know it's hard to describe a problem like this, or maybe I couldn't make it clearer, please ask me if you need more info.

Any help would save me in a long.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Check for syntax error in the question

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I commented out the note, Now please point me where are the syntax error you are.

Comment: There’s missing quotes right before ngmodel

Comment: @Simon_Weaver for pointing out!

Comment: Can you try article_category_detail?.category_details_language_id instead article_category_detail.category_details_language_id

Comment: @LokeshDaiya It says > `Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 55 in [article_category_detail?.category_details_language_id=$event]`